# Retorno de dados JSON sem espaçamento

Tags: java, json

tenho uma classe que possui um único método para fazer uma requisição de dados que estão  no formato JSON e retornar um único campo "fantasia" que no meu caso é armazenado na variável nomeEmpresa.

Essa classe funciona perfeitamente, o único problema é que o meu resultado está perdendo os espaçamentos entre o nome da empresa. Segue abaixo um exemplo e o código.

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

**Exemplo:**

O que eu quero após a consulta: Supermercado Novo

O que estou recebendo após a consulta: SupermercadoNovo

**Código:**

```
public class NomeFantasia {

    public String nomeEmpresa;

    public String nomeFantasiaMetodo(String cnpj){

        StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/" + cnpj);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.connect();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                resposta.append(scanner.next());
            }

            JSONObject my_obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(resposta));
            nomeEmpresa = my_obj.getString("fantasia");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return nomeEmpresa;


    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Lucas, por favor deixa a primeira letra da frase em maiúsculo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, basta trocar o resposta.append(scanner.next()); por resposta.append(scanner.nextLine());